# 'lme' error R "attempt to apply non-function

Tags: r, nlme

I'm conducting lme analysis using on my dataset with the following code

```
M1 <- lme(VT ~ visit + sx + agevis + c_bmi + gpa + qa + BP + MH + ethn, data = Cleaned_data4t300919, random = ~ 1 + visit |id, corAR1(),method = "ML", na.action = na.omit(Cleaned_data4t300919))
```

and I get the following error message:

> Error in model.frame.default(formula = ~visit + sx + agevis + c_bmi + 
>   :    attempt to apply non-function

I am not sure what I am doing wrong or how to get the model to run. I really appreciate an answer. Thank you.

I am trying to run a linear mixed effect model with VT as my dependent variable, visit as my time variable, with a 1st order autoregressive correlation, ML estimator on data with some missing observations.

I have tried changing the code in the following ways but got the same error message

```
library(nlme)
?lme
fm2 <- lme(VT ~ visit + sx + agevis + c_bmi + gpa + qa + BP + MH + ethn, data = Cleaned_data4t300919, random = ~ 1|id, corAR1(),method = "ML", na.action = na.pass(Cleaned_data4t300919))

fm2 <- lme(VT ~ visit + sx + agevis + c_bmi + gpa + qa + BP + sfnMH + ethn, data = Cleaned_data4t300919, random = ~ 1 + visit |cenid, corAR1(),method = "ML", na.action = na.omit(Cleaned_data4t300919))

fm2 <- lme(VT ~ visit + sx + agevis , data = Cleaned_data4t300919, random = ~ 1 + visit |id, corAR1(),method = "ML", na.action = na.omit(Cleaned_data4t300919))

fm2 <- lme(VT~visit + sx + agevis + c_bmi + gpa + qa + BP + MH + ethn, data = Cleaned_data4t300919, na.action = na.exclude(Cleaned_data4t300919))

fm2 <- lme(formula= sfnVT ~ visit + sx + agevis , data = Cleaned_data4t300919, random = ~ 1 + visit |cenid, corAR1(),method = "ML", na.action = na.omit(Cleaned_data4t300919))
```

I will like to obtain the estimates for the code and plot estimates using ggplot.

Comment: `na.action = na.omit(Cleaned_data4t300919)` is the problem I think. From `?lme` - *na.action: a function that indicates what should happen when the data
          contain 'NA's* - you are providing data, not a function. A way to identify these kinds of issues for sure is to use `debug` - `debug(lme)` then step through the function line-by-line to see exactly what the error is in response to.

Comment: @thelatemail, post as answer?

Comment: @BenBolker - upgraded to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
na.action = na.omit(Cleaned_data4t300919)
```

and similar attempts are the problem I think.

From `?lme`:

> na.action: a function that indicates what should happen when the data
>   contain 'NA's

You are providing data, not a function, since `na.omit(dataset)` returns a `data.frame` with `NA` containing rows removed, rather than something that can be applied to the `data=` specified. Just:

```
na.action=na.omit
```

or similar `na.*` functions will be sufficient.

A way to identify these kinds of issues for sure is to use `?debug` - `debug(lme)` then step through the function line-by-line to see exactly what the error is in response to.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. i'm new to R and I don't quite understand your answer. could you give an example.

Comment: @sylvie - e.g.: just `na.action=na.omit` should be enough, you don't need to specify the dataset again as well.